# How to convert daily data to weekly data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data frame in pandas

```
  Date         Doctor_Code  Patient_Code    Patient_Type    Net_Amount  Depat               Flag
  2013-01-21    217         191             STAFF           0.0         Cardiac Medicine    1
  2014-01-22    202         323             CORPORATE       100         GENERAL SURGICAL    1
  2013-01-23    202         395             PAYING          150.0       GENERAL SURGICAL    1
  2012-01-24    339         410             PAYING          100.0       ONCO SURGERY        1
  2013-01-25    3           5530            STAFF           0.0         Cardiac Medicine    1
  2013-01-26    217         191             STAFF           0.0         Cardiac Medicine    1
  2014-01-27    202         323             CORPORATE       100         GENERAL SURGICAL    1
  2013-01-28    202         395             PAYING          150.0       GENERAL SURGICAL    1
  2012-01-29    339         410             PAYING          100.0       ONCO SURGERY        1
  2013-01-30    3           5530            STAFF           0.0         Cardiac Medicine    1
```

I want to convert this daily data into weekly data grouping by `Depart, Doctor_Code, Patient_Type` with following aggregations.

1. `Patient_Code` - Unique count at weekly level
2. `Net_Amount` - sum at weekly level
3. `Flag` - sum st weekly level

I am doing following in pandas

```
  weekly_data = df.groupby(['Doctor_Code', 'Patient_Type', 'Depart']).resample('W', 
                           on='Date').agg({'Patient_Code': nunique,
                                            'Flag':'sum',
                                            'Net_Amount':'sum',
                                          }).reset_index().sort_values(by='Date')
```

How to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is build a year + week colum to group on :

```py
df['YearWeek'] = df['Date'].dt.year.astype(str) + df['Date'].dt.week.astype(str)

weekly_data = (df.groupby(['Doctor_Code', 'Patient_Type', 'Depart', 'YearWeek'])
                 .agg({'Patient_Code': 'nunique',
                       'Flag':'sum',
                       'Net_Amount':'sum',
                      })
                 .reset_index()
                 .sort_values(by='Date')
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract week of the year, `groupby` week of year and aggregate using `agg`

```
 df['weekofyear']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%U')



  df.groupby(['weekofyear','Depat','Doctor_Code','Patient_Type'])\
.agg(Patient_Code=('Patient_Code','nunique'),Net_Amount=('Net_Amount','sum')\
     ,Flag=('Flag','sum')).reset_index()

 weekofyear            Depat  Doctor_Code Patient_Type  Patient_Code  \
0         03  CardiacMedicine            3        STAFF             1   
1         03  CardiacMedicine          217        STAFF             1   
2         03  GENERALSURGICAL          202    CORPORATE             1   
3         03  GENERALSURGICAL          202       PAYING             1   
4         04  CardiacMedicine            3        STAFF             1   
5         04  GENERALSURGICAL          202    CORPORATE             1   
6         04  GENERALSURGICAL          202       PAYING             1   
7         04      ONCOSURGERY          339       PAYING             1   
8         05      ONCOSURGERY          339       PAYING             1   

   Net_Amount  Flag  
0         0.0     1  
1         0.0     2  
2       100.0     1  
3       150.0     1  
4         0.0     1  
5       100.0     1  
6       150.0     1  
7       100.0     1  
8       100.0     1
```